# How to add adsense code after 1st paragraph only in genesis?

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I want to display adsense ad after the first paragraph only. can one please guide me with proper code.

Comment: need without plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the manual way with the following code. It's very efficent and very fast:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'prefix_process_content', 20);

function prefix_process_content($content){

$needle = '</p>';

$replace= '</p>your ad code here'; // do not forget the </p>

// Get the position of the first occurrence of $needle
$pos = strpos($content, $needle);

// if found
if ($pos !== false) {
    $newstring = substr_replace($content, $replace, $pos, strlen($needle));
}

return $newstring;

}
```

I did not test it, but should be working. If you need help with that code let me know.

If you are using WordPress you can use a plugin which can do that like `WP QUADS`. It only adds no to very little overhead and does not increase the loading times of your site. https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-adsense-reloaded/

It's maintained and tested with latest WordPress version!

Disclaimer: I am the author of the plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a plugin, you can use `Insert Post Ads` https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-post-ads/

And here is a quick tutorial how to set it up: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-insert-ads-within-your-post-content-in-wordpress/